# Android: nullpointerexception when enabling the button

Tags: android

I am trying to enable a button when check box is checked , but iam getting `nullpointerexception`

```
viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(Constants.checkBoxState[position]);


        final Button savebtn1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.savebtn);
        viewHolder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                    // Toast.makeText(activity, "checked" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Constants.checkBoxState[position] = true;
                    Constants.selectedContacts.add(listCont.get(position));
                    savebtn1.setEnabled(true);
                } else {

                    Constants.checkBoxState[position] = false;
                    Constants.selectedContacts.remove(listCont.get(position));

                }

            }
        });
```

Any idea?

Comment: can you show stacktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final Button savebtn1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.savebtn);
```

you are getting `NullPointerException` because `R.id.savebtn` is not inside `view`

Comment: yes ..actually the button is from different layout, how to proceed now?

Comment: you can put inside view and play with the visibility... of course that depends on your constraints

Comment: please suggest me how to do that, how to put inside view?

Comment: I mean put it inside the layout you use to create the view object. Post the complete method

Comment: i cannot change the layout ...i inflated the button and tried but no action is happening  http://pastebin.com/nGgNWqLD

Comment: you should use setEnabled not setVisibility. The inflater should work

Comment: how to make button invisible initially..in layout file i used android:enable=false, but i want the button completely invisible and should be visible after i check the checkbox

Comment: you should use the android:visibility property. android:visibility="invisible" for instance

Comment: tried that ..but no action is happening..the button is not enableing  :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try to clean your project

```
Project -> Clean
```

Sometimes Eclipse fails when building R.java.